# Fetch JSON function not working properly. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I have created a function named `fetchJSONData()` that is supposed to return a JavaScript object from the URL you give it, and when you console.log the output, it works as expected, but when I try to access a property from the returned object, it shows `undefined` as the property value.

Here is the small json file I am using:

```
{
    "headerText": "Lorem Ipsum",
    "subText": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....."
}
```

Here is a very basic example code snippet:

```js
async function fetchJSONData(url) {
    var response = await fetch(url);
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

var textTest = fetchJSONData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
var test01 = document.getElementById("test01");
var test02 = document.getElementById("test02");

window.onload = function() {
    // Returns undefined
    test01.innerText = textTest.title;
    test02.innerText = textTest.body;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="test01">blank</h1>
    <p id="test02">blank</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see when I try to access the variables, the html elements show the value is undefined.

Comment: `fetchJSONData` is `async` and returns a _promise_. You can either `await` it (by calling it within an `async` function), or make it "thenable": `fetchJSONData(endpoint).then(data => ...`.

Comment: @Andy The function is already an async function, and I am awaiting for the response.json();

Comment: Yes, and you have to `await` it: `const data = await fetchJSONData(endpoint)`. But to do that you either need to place the code for that inside another `async` function, or make it thenable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to access `textTest.title` and `textTest.body`. The JSON structure in your JSON file does not contain the `title` and `body`  properties, so they will be `undefined`.

Your code snippet, on the other hand, refers to a URL with a different JSON structure. If this is what you're using, the property names should be OK.

But, when the `window.onload` event handler runs, the promise returned from `fetchJSONData` will not have resolved (also, it returns a promise, so you would have to `await` it.).
You can solve this by moving your DOM update logic into the `fetchJSONData` function:

```js
async function fetchJSONData(url) {
    var response = await fetch(url);
    var data = await response.json();
    var test01 = document.getElementById("test01");
    var test02 = document.getElementById("test02");
    test01.innerText = data.title;
    test02.innerText = data.body;
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

var textTest = fetchJSONData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");

window.onload = function() {
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="test01">blank</h1>
    <p id="test02">blank</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, the code in the snippet above is using an example json file, which contains the properties .title and .body

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but instead of moving the window.onload logic into the function, I will add a new parameter that takes in a function that will execute after the response has been resolved.